# CakePHP containable, group by in containable

Tags: php, pagination, cakephp-2.0

I have a table called People

Like this:

```
ID    BillID    FirstName    LastName
1       1           x            y
2       1           z            t
3       2           v            w
```

The relation is one to many (each Bill has many People)

so I want to paginate this way:

I want to have all people of (for instance) 5 different Bills in each page

How should I make the query?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried group by clause?

In cakephp use below line in

**$this->Paginator->settings**

```
'group' => array('billid')
```

Comment: I get this error when using group 
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'Bills.AdultCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: BTW I'm using a custom find type

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html

See the correct syntex here

Comment: Custom find is OK. The problem is with Group By